# Errors deserializing pac4j profiles

Tags: pac4j

We use `play-pac4j` in [CiviForm](https://civiform.us/), an open-source, public interest project. Our user profiles are represented by the [`CiviFormProfileData`](https://github.com/civiform/civiform/blob/v1.43.0/server/app/auth/CiviFormProfileData.java) subclass of `o.p.c.p.CommonProfile`.

In our logs, we have noted warnings like this:

```
[warn] o.p.c.u.s.JavaSerializer - cannot Java deserialize object
java.io.InvalidClassException: auth.CiviFormProfileData; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 3142603030317816700, local class serialVersionUID = 6503846375980947185
```

This surprises us, because we expected profile serialization to be stable. Note that we did **not** have `serialVersionUID` set for this subclass, which was an oversight (and is addressed by [this PR](https://github.com/civiform/civiform/pull/6063)). That being said, though the class has had some [small changes](https://github.com/civiform/civiform/commits/v1.43.0/server/app/auth/CiviFormProfileData.java) recently, the *structure* of the class did not change.

1. Is this behavior expected?
2. If so, is setting `serialVersionUID` to the current value sufficient to guard against this problem in the future?

GitHub issue: [Errors deserializing pac4j profiles](https://github.com/civiform/civiform/issues/6069)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profile serialization should be stable.

We have faced issues using the `JavaSerializer` so this has been changed in the `pac4j` core project to use the `JsonSerializer`.

This is not the case with `play-pac4j` and the `PlayCookieSessionStore`. I guess we should change that.

What play-pac4j version do you use?

Comment: We are currently using `11.1.0-PLAY2.8` ([reference](https://github.com/civiform/civiform/blob/1855ca4643104e1f9a080d3f2b9b60be2bc22658/server/build.sbt#L71)).

Comment: Stable serialization is of course highly desirable. 

Switching to JSON serialization would cause all existing profiles to be incompatible with a new release of our server, which is something we would have to think through carefully.

For now, would setting `serialVersionUID` to match the currently-computed value make it less likely that non-structural changes to the profile class result in instability?

Comment: I should do that for the next major version (12.x). Adding the `serialVersionUID` would help, but the JSON approach will be safer.

Comment: Thank you. In that release, please consider making the serializer configurable, so that we would be able to upgrade while retaining Java serialization if we decide it is most important to retain compatibility with existing profiles.

Comment: JSON serialization is now used for play-pac4j v12. You can still set a `JavaSerializer` if need be.

Comment: Good to know, thank you.

Is there an appreciable difference in cookie size using JSON serialization instead of Java?

Comment: Data are zipped, so it should make little difference between using JSON or Java: https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j/blob/master/shared/src/main/java/org/pac4j/play/store/PlayCookieSessionStore.java#L158